# How to convert array with same object to single object in swift?

Tags: swift

I have array of object. Array object have two values time(string) and feelingcheck(Bool). for particular date i have multiple objects. but i want to convert them into single object. Means only one object of particular time(string). feelingcheck(Bool)(if there is atleast one false i want to make its value as false).

i have array like

```
       var checkDB: [CheckModel(time: "Sunday, 7 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: false),
        CheckModel(time: "Monday, 8 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: true),
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: true), 
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: true), 
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: false), 
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: true), 
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: false), 
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: false), 
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: true), 
        CheckModel(time: "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020", feelingCheck: false)]
```

i am trying to make logic but getting confused. is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Set`. In order to be able to do that, you'll need to make your `CheckModel` conform to `Hashable` though.

```
let uniqueChecks = Set(checkDB)
```

The set will only contain 1 instance of each matching object.

Comment: Thanks for help.. i will try that..but my other value in object is keep changing ..in this case will Set help me?

Comment: @user7423463 you can define which properties to use for equality when you conform to `Hashable`. If you add both `time` and `feelingCheck` to your `==` implementation, then you'll get your desired results with `Set`.

Comment: If `CheckModel` is `struct`(and all properties conform to `Hashable`) you may be given free implementation of `==` (and `hashValue`) too

Comment: If == only uses time then it will be random if a feelingCheck with true or false will be selected or? and if both properties is used in == then there might be 2 objects per `time` value

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi step solution but it is written in one line

First the array is grouped into a dictionary using `time` as key and then the dictionary is reduced into an array with one object per key and a check using `contains` to see if `feelingCheck` should be true or false

```
let merged = Dictionary(grouping: checkDB, by: { $0.time })
    .reduce(into: []) { $0.append(CheckModel(time: $1.key, feelingCheck: !$1.value.contains(where: { $0.feelingCheck == false})))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and It works locally

```
    let finalCheckModels = [[CheckModel]](Dictionary(grouping: checkDB, by: { $0.time }).values)
        .map {
        $0.contains(where: { $0.feelingCheck == false }) ?
            $0.map { CheckModel(time: $0.time, feelingCheck: false) } :
            $0
    }

    print(finalCheckModels)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nifty trick where you can break the array into key-value pairs, combine them into unique keys of `time` with your own logic for values of conflicting keys, and map back into array of `CheckModel` objects:

```
var uniques = Dictionary(checkDB.map{($0.time, $0.feelingCheck)}, uniquingKeysWith: { $0 && $1 }).map(CheckModel.init)
```

Order, however, is not guaranteed, i.e. "Wednesday, 10 Jun 2020" could come before "Sunday, 7 Jun 2020".

That being said, for all the one-liners suggested here, I would suggest optimizing for whatever makes it clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the steps using basic looping constructs so that your confusion is removed as for how to put the logic. These statements can be reduced to single-liner or probably 2-liner using map and reduce functions:

```
var checkDict = [String: Bool]()
for item in checkDB {
    checkDict[item.time] = (checkDict[item.time] ?? true) && item.feelingCheck
}

// If you want to alter the same array
checkDB.removeAll()
for (key, value) in checkDict {
    checkDB.append(CheckModel(time: key, feelingCheck: value))
}

// If you want the result in a separate array
var newCheckDB = [CheckModel]()
for (key, value) in checkDict {
    newCheckDB.append(CheckModel(time: key, feelingCheck: value))
}
```